# PHPMailer attachment type and size limit

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have one form and i am using PHPMailer to send data from that form to my email. Users can send attachments as well, but i have one rpoblem: how to make PHPMailer to deny attachments larger than 2Mb and to allow only iamge attachments (no other types of documents)?

This is code i using for multiply email attachments with PHPMailer:

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['fileAttach']['name']) as $key) {

   $source = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
   $filename = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$key]; 

   $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check the filesize using [`filesize()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and the type using [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

the resulting code could look like:

```
$maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
$types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'); // allowed mime-types

if(filesize($filename) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($filename),$types)){
  $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

**EDIT:** PHPMailer doesn't have a built-in possibility for those chacks - as you can see from the source, it only checks if the file exists when adding an attachment:

```
if ( !@is_file($path) ) {
  throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang('file_access') . $path, self::STOP_CONTINUE);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i wanted to do something like that, but i was wonderind is there some "builtin" PHPMailer function to do this? But probably not, i tried to find it on site...

Answer (score 0):

Use [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) for checking the file size. For checking if the file is a image use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) which returns false if it's not an image, else it will return an array of info including mimetype (if you wan't to check for specific image types).

Answer (score 0):

1. In PHPMailer you have [getAttachments()](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L3261) function that return an array of attachments
2. Loop on this array
3. If there is an attachment uses file_size(), if it's a string attachments convert it from base64 to file and use file_size()

Et voila !