# Limiting attachment type and file size on PHPMailer contact form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, phpmailer, contact-form

I've created a contact form, which allows for the upload of 3 files. Currently there is no limitation to the file size and file type.
I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Limit the file type to "png,gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp"
2. Limit the file size to 5mb

I'm currently using PHPMailer to send the contact form via SMTP.

My contact_mail.php contents:

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = FALSE;
$mail->Port     = 25;  
$mail->Host     = "###HIDDEN###";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("###HIDDEN###");  
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->Body='Name:  '.$_POST['userName'].'<br />
Telephone:  '.$_POST['telephone'].'<br />
Nationality:  '.$_POST['nationality'].'<br />
Age:  '.$_POST['age'].'<br />
Height:  '.$_POST['height'].'<br/>
Favourites:  '.$_POST['age'].'<br />
Bio:  '.$_POST['content'];

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']    ['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile2']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile2']['name']); 
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile3']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile3']['name']); 
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
} else {
echo "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
}   
?>
```

Form content:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 labelPanel">
<label>Portfolio Images</label><br/>
<input type="file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile" class="inputField">
<input type="file" name="attachmentFile2" id="attachmentFile" class="inputField">
<input type="file" name="attachmentFile3" id="attachmentFile" class="inputField">
</div>
```

PHP code & validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e){
$("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#loader-icon').show();
var valid;  
valid = validateContact();
if(valid) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "contact_mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
    $("#mail-status").html(data);
    $('#loader-icon').hide();
    },
    error: function(){}             

    });
}
}));

function validateContact() {
var valid = true;   
$(".inputField").css('background-color','');
$(".info").html('');

if(!$("#userName").val()) {
    $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userName").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#telephone").val()) {
    $("#telephone-info").html("(required)");
    $("#telephone").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#nationality").val()) {
    $("#nationality-info").html("(required)");
    $("#nationality").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#age").val()) {
    $("#age-info").html("(required)");
    $("#age").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#height").val()) {
    $("#height-info").html("(required)");
    $("#height").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#favourites").val()) {
    $("#favourites-info").html("(required)");
    $("#favourites").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#subject").val()) {
    $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
    $("#subject").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#content").val()) {
    $("#content-info").html("(required)");
    $("#content").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}

return valid;
}

});
</script>
```

I'm quite new to PHP so I've followed a tutorial online to create the contact form as it is - unfortunately when it comes to validation on image upload, I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer attachment type and size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947228/phpmailer-attachment-type-and-size-limit)

Comment: You tutorial is out of date (and unsafe), and it should have referred you to the PHP docs on how to handle uploads. [Get the latest version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on the examples provided, particularly [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps). Thre are lots of ways of validating and sanitising images - look into imagemagick, [for example](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23560).

Comment: Thanks @Synchro for letting me know that it was unsafe, I thought as much as it isn't limiting file types. As well as no captcha/human validation. Thanks for linking me to that example file - I'll get on building it again.

Comment: It's mainly that you're not checking the status of uploaded files before using them - you need to use `move_uploaded_file`, as the PHPMailer example does.