# PHPMailer sanitizing multiple attachments

Tags: php

I am trying to limit the file size and type of attachments processed by phpmailer. The answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947228/phpmailer-attachment-type-and-size-limit) does not solve the multiple attachments issue. The issue seems to be the form's input name with [] which converts form input to array. I am not able to write its correct syntax.

HTML is:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="attach_file[]" />
```

PHP is:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

    $mail->setFrom('abc@abc.org', 'abc');
    $mail->addAddress('xyz@xyz.com', 'xyz');              

    // Attachments

foreach(array_keys($_FILES['attach_file']['name']) as $key) {

   $source = $_FILES['attach_file']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
   $filename = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$key]; 
$mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}

    $mail->isHTML(true); 

    $mail->Subject = 'Case History';

    $mail->Body = $name;

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';

} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

If in foreach loop I use this:

```
$maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
$types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'); // allowed mime-types

if(filesize($filename) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($filename),$types)){
  $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

I get these errors :

1. filesize(): stat failed
2. mime_content_type(): failed to open stream.
3. No such file or directory

What is the correct way of writing the IF condition when input name is for multiple attachments. Thanks.

Comment: I guess your `$filename` is only the filename without the directory prefix, so checking on it won't work. Store the absolute filename in an additional variable and check against it.

Comment: yes you are correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should note that `$filename` is just the original name of the file that has been uploaded (e.g. `photo.jpg`) - but the filesystem pathname of the uploaded file is actually `$source` (always some random filename, sitting in the OS temp folder).

Comment: that resolved, thank you so much. due to my reputation of less than 15 my vote for accepting the answer will not be displayed, sorry about that.